# How to return an empty vector

Tags: java, vector

This method finds all Alien objects in the AlienList object’s Vector whose humanoid field has the value false. It stores all matching Alien objects in a new Vector that is then returned from the method. The method must also remove all the matching Alien objects from the Vector of AlienList. If there are no matching Alien objects then an empty Vector must be returned.

The only problem with my method is that when i call the method for a second time, the same two (removed) non humanoids which were returned in the first method call, are actually in this list returned by the 2nd call. Which they should have not been because they were removed on the previous call.

Here is my class with the method i need help with at the bottom:

```
public class AlientList
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private Vector<Alien> aliens;
    private Vector<Alien> nonHumanoids;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class AlientList
     */
    public AlientList()
    {
        aliens = new Vector<>();
        nonHumanoids = new Vector<>();
    }

    public void addAlien(Alien alien)
    {
        aliens.add(alien);
    }

    public void printHumanoids()
    {
        for(Alien alien: aliens) { 
            if(alien.getHumanoid() == true){    
                System.out.println(alien.getDetails());
            }
        }
    }

    public Vector<Alien> getNonHumanoids()
    {
        Iterator<Alien> it = aliens.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Alien alien = it.next();
            if(alien.getHumanoid() == false){
                it.remove();
                nonHumanoids.add(alien);
            }
        }
        return nonHumanoids; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want your methods to return new Lists/Vectors that get filled inside the methods, you need to create new Lists/vectors inside those methods. Currently you have `private Vector<Alien> nonHumanoids` as an instance variable that you add new items into each time you call `getNonHumanoids()`. Not having this instance variable and instead creating an instance as a local variable inside the `getNonHumanoids()` method would be a better fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why add an `Alien` to the wrong list in the first place? btw, you should probably use `ArrayList` over `Vector` The latter is legacy and unecessarily (normally) synchronized. Also you method would be better called `isHumanoid` ("getX" implies a non-boolean accessor)